# Почему по разному работает запрос

Tags: jquery

Вот так запрос пашет

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_rooms_place', function() {
val = $(this).attr('data-id');
place = $(this).parents('.type_rooms_wc').children('.rooms_place_list');
$.ajax({
  url: '/admin/hotels/get_view_rooms_place',
  data: 'id_rooms=' + val,
  type: "post",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result) {
    place.append();
  }
});
```

а Вот так нет

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_rooms_place', function() {
val = $(this).attr('data-id');$.ajax({
  url: '/admin/hotels/get_view_rooms_place',
  data: 'id_rooms=' + val,
  type: "post",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(result) {
    $(this).parents('.type_rooms_wc').children('.rooms_place_list').append();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Во втором примере опечатка похоже:

```
val = $(this).attr('data-id');.ajax({
```

**ajax** от чего берется?

---

**но это еще не все:**

```
success: function(result) {
   $(this).parents('.type_rooms_wc').children('.rooms_place_list').append();
}
```

в данном случае **$(this)** будет другим объектом, т.к. **this** берется для функции `success: function(result) {` - и скорее всего это будет *undefind*

Comment: нет не опечатка.. просто не перенесена строка

Comment: может быть val = $(this).attr('data-id'); $.ajax({...

Comment: @ukroficer я посмотрел ваши изменения вопроса, .ajax - просто опечатка при написании вопроса, и дальше откопал еще одну ошибку )

Comment: Очень благодарю но где это задокументировано?

Comment: Эм, хотябы тут: http://javascript.ru/this

> Оператор this возвращает ссылку на объект, являющийся текущим контекстом вызова. Это позволяет обращаться к свойствам "текущего" объекта: this.property.